# MySQL get nearest value by date

Tags: mysql, date, join

I have following table where I store the customer counts every week

```
| area    | date       | count |
|---------|------------|-------|
| AREA I  | 2016-03-20 | 530   |
| AREA I  | 2016-03-13 | 520   |
| AREA II | 2016-03-20 | 370   |
```

Now I want to get the nearest customer count by date value at another table. So if I give f.ex. date `2016-03-15` it should return 520 for `AREA I` and 370 for `AREA II`.

Example query:

```
SELECT a.period, a.area, b.customerCount FROM periods a
JOIN customer_count b ON (...)
GROUP BY a.period, a.area
```

I think that I should be using `ABS()` and `DATEDIFF()` somehow but I didn't get that. Or is there some other way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
SELECT a.period, a.area, b.customerCount FROM periods a
JOIN customer_count b ON (...)
GROUP BY a.period, a.area
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF( `date`, NOW()))
```

Comment: Am I right that this orders results after grouping? I think they must be ordered in `JOIN`